# Python - Count number of integers in a string?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm just getting back into python and was wondering if there is an easy way to return the number of integers that exist in a given string.

For example if I had a list,

```
['1 5','2 10 23','214 33 1']
```

iterating through each item in the list and finding the number of integers would return `2`, `3`, and `3`, respectively.

The only thing I can think of would be to have a 2-dimensional list, where each item in the main list is another list that holds the separate numbers, and then I could call len() on each secondary list. Is there an easier way?

Comment: You need to show what you tried first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension. This requires that integers are split by a space ' ' in your list of strings.

```
data = ['1 5','2 10 23','214 33 1']
int_per_string = [len(x.split(' ')) for x in data]
```

Returns:

```
Out[8]:[2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you! I forgot how powerful lists are in python.

Answer (score 0):

According to the example you kept, for each item in your list  they were separated with spaces. So you can try using  **.isdigit()**

```
    numCount=[]
    for item in list:
        index=0
        sublist = item.split()
        for subitem in sublist:
            if subitem.isdigit():
                index +=1
        numCount.append(index)
    print(numCount)
```

I hope this will help you. You can also use **subitem.isalnum()**  instead of **subitem.isdigit()**  if you want to check for a number which is included along with a string.

Thank you.